# QHttpMultiPart doesn't send any packets

Tags: c++, qt5

I've got some basic qt code that I am using to send a POST request to a webserver. At the moment I am judging success of this code based on whether or not it actually sends any packets at all. It currently does not. The input argument for this function is the name of a file that exists.

```
void do_firmware_update(QString file)
{
    QFile *firmware_file = new QFile(file);
    firmware_file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    QNetworkAccessManager * mgr = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    QHttpPart *fileDataPart = new QHttpPart;
    fileDataPart->setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + file + "\""));
    fileDataPart->setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("application/octet-stream"));
    fileDataPart->setBodyDevice(firmware_file);

    QHttpPart *textPart = new QHttpPart;
    textPart->setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    textPart->setBody("my text");

    QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);
    firmware_file->setParent(multiPart);
    multiPart->append(*textPart);
    multiPart->append(*fileDataPart);



    QUrl url = QUrl::fromUserInput("http://192.168.5.3:8080/upload");
    url.setScheme("http");
    qDebug() << "Host:" << url.host();
    qDebug() << "Port:" << url.port();
    QNetworkRequest *req = new QNetworkRequest(url);
    QNetworkReply::NetworkError ne2;
    QNetworkReply *p = mgr->post(*req, multiPart);
    while (!p->isFinished())
    {
        p = mgr->post(*req, multiPart);
        ne2 = p->error();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `mgr->post` is asynchronous, you're not giving the event loop time to send out the  request and receive the response.

Comment: @botje Yes that is what the problem is. Thank you for this insight. I was unable to locate this piece of info in the documentation.